# Verify that a JS script only runs in whitelisted native apps

Tags: javascript, webview, verification

We have a chat interface that we allow our partners to embed into their websites and web apps using a JS snippet. We want to expand to integrating with native apps using WebViews.

I am seeking an approach to verify that our snippet is only running in specific apps.

As an example: A similar functionality that is easily achieved in web apps is a domain check.

- A partner / client gets a JS snippet or a URL and a key,
- on page load it looks up the partner details using the key,
- if they're active and approved for this service,
- check the requesting domain against a list of whitelisted domains for this key.

Is it possible to uniquely identify a native app from a JavaScript function that is running in a WebView to verify the app? Perhaps - are app store unique app IDs accessible from within a WebView?

Thank you

Comment: One way to ensure that a JS snippet is running in a verified and whitelisted app is to use a signed script. This involves digitally signing the script using a private key and then verifying the signature using the public key. The public key can then be used to verify the script in the webview, ensuring that it has not been tampered with and that it is coming from a trusted source. Additionally, you can add additional checks to the webview such as checking the URL of the script or the origin of the request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I think this is the wrong side of the same coin. I do not need to verify a script before loading it into my app, rather to verify an app before loading my script into it (or before executing code if this check happens after load).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to uniquely identify a native app from a JavaScript function that is running in a WebView.

"No" is a hard answer to find on the web. Phone a friend informed me that while some native information and functionality is accessible from within WebViews, the app ID or bundle identifier is not exposed programmatically. Of course a developer could add it, but that's not helpful in verification.